# Proving two metrics induce the same topology

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

Let $d_E$ be the standard Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $d_{\infty}$ be the metric given by $d_{\infty} (x,y) = \max\limits_{1 \leq i \leq n} \{|x_i - y_i|\}$, which also gives rise to a metric space on $\mathbb{R}^n$. I want to prove that $d_E$ and $d_{\infty}$ induce the same topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$. There are two things about this I want to ask about.

(1) The hint I'm given is consider the $n=2$ case and draw a picture. I have no intuition as to how this will help me or how to motivates the proof, so some intuition would be very helpful.

(2) I've seen a proof of how to do this and I understand it fully, but again, I don't know how I would come up with it. Another hint I have is to prove the existence of $C > 0$ such that $d_{\infty} (x,y) \leq d_E (x,y) \leq C d_{\infty} (x,y)$. The appropriate value of $C$ ends up being $\sqrt{n}$. Then, I prove as lemmas that for any $B_r (p)$ (an open ball with respect to the Euclidean metric), I have $B_r (p) \subset B^{\infty}_r (p)$ and $B^{\infty}_{r/\sqrt{n}} (p) \subset B_r (p)$.  I can then prove that a subset $E$ is open with respect to $d_E$ if and only if it is open with respect to $d_{\infty}$.

I'm able to follow all of the steps, but I have no intuition for how I would come up with it or how a picture would motivate this. I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The metric $d_E$ measures the usual distance between points. The metric $d_\infty$ measures the difference between the coordinates which are farthest apart.A ball (say, two dimensional) according to the first metric is a disk on the plane. A ball according to the second is a square. Namely, $\{(x,y):d_\infty((x,y),(0,0))\le R\}$ is just the square $[-R,R]^2$. All you need to prove is that there is always an axis-aligned square within a given disk, and there is always a disk within a given square. If you start with a square of side $2R$, you can consider the inner tangent circle, which has radius $R$. This is what $B_r(p)\subset B_r^\infty(p)$ means. Given a circle of radius $R$, the inscribed square has side $R/\sqrt{2}$. This is what $B_{r/\sqrt{2}}^\infty(p)\subset B_r(p)$ means. In higher dimensions it is the same, but you have to replace $\sqrt{2}$ by $\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: This is extremely helpful, thank you very much. The only question I have is, how do you know that the inner tangent circle has radius $R$, and the inner inscribed square has side $R/\sqrt{2}$? I'm trying, but failing, to prove either of these.

Comment: If you draw a circle tangent to a square (inside the square), its diameter is exactly the side of the square, so its radius is half of it, $2R/2=R$. If you draw a circle circumscribed to a square, its radius is half of the diagonal of the square, $\frac 1{2}\sqrt{2}\cdot 2R=\sqrt{2}R$